# Is it possible to add to filter_var() function user-defined parameters?

Tags: php

I am using 'filter_var()' function with FILTER_CALLBACK.
Something like this:

```
$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => 'my_func'));
```

my_func() usually receives the $value as an argument:

```
function my_func($val)
{
    if (some cond)
    {
        return $val;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use another $var in my_func() from the outer scope (I mean with the filter_var()).
One option is to declare it as global in the function. Another is to pass it as argument.
How can I avoid declaring global and pass the $var as argument?

Comment: This may be help to you : http://codepad.org/dTNRVOl1

Comment: If you're writing a callback function anyway, why not just write a dedicated function for this particular filter and pass it any parameters you need?

Comment: because the filter_var is used in a loop and info which filters for which value to be used is stored in a separate array. it will be too expensive and ugly to check for each value whether it is the one, that needs another functuion

Comment: Have you tried using [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)? I edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.3+, you could use closures:

```
function my_func($val, $arg1, $arg2)
{
    return $arg1.': '.$val.' '.$arg2;
}

$testVar = 'test';
$result = filter_var($testVar, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => function($var) {
    return my_func($var, 'someValue', 'someOtherValue');
}));

var_dump($result); // string(30) "someValue: test someOtherValue"
```

Of course, this example doesn't really "validate" anything, just changes the text a bit, but it should give you an idea of how it works.

**EDIT:** Judging from the comments, you want to use a certain function for certain values without checking which one to use at each loop. Have you considered using [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)? Here's an example:

```
function myFunc1($arg1, $arg2) { return 'Executed myFunc1 with arguments: '.$arg1.' '.$arg2; }
function myFunc2($arg1, $arg2) { return 'Executed myFunc2 with arguments: '.$arg1.' '.$arg2; }

$functionsToUse = array(
    'myFunc1',
    'myFunc2'
);

foreach ($functionsToUse as $func)
{
    echo call_user_func($func, 'value', 'another value').'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Is is kind of a solution, but its problem is that now I am unable to perform standard validations in the loop. (I take the "FILTER_CALLBACK" from the values type settings array, so it can be any other validator). I understand that I can check for each value what filter to use.

Comment: How about the first method I suggested? Get the variables from the loop with "global" (e.g. global $var1, $var2;) from inside the closure (as far as I know, they will only be "global" for the closure, which disappears after its been used, so it's not really a problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_func($val,$val2=null)
{
    if (some cond)
    {
        return $val;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I pass the argument with the filter_var()?

Comment: think you can use filter_var_array($data, $args);

Comment: As I can see from php.net is the same as filter_var, but for many variables. It still uses filter_var with ONE user-defined variable in options of FILTER_CALLBACK.