# php function does not work when passing variable as argument

Tags: php

Pls see my code below, which is meant to validate whether a variable has on of the specific value (and based on solution example of [Is it possible to add to filter_var() function user-defined parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343377/is-it-possible-to-add-to-filter-var-function-user-defined-parameters))

I tested two cases (A, B) as descibed in the comments in the code below.
I dont understand why the function is not working properly in case B? (which I tested by means of ideone.com)

```
function validate_select($val, $myoptions)
{
//print_r($myoptions);
for($i=0;$i<count($myoptions);$i++){
    if($val==$myoptions[$i]){
        return $val;
    }
}
    return false;
}

$testVar = 'apple';
$myoptions = array('banana','pear','apple');
$result = filter_var($testVar, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => function($var) {
  //return validate_select($var, array('banana','pear','apple')); //case A: returns correct value 'apple'
  return validate_select($var, $myoptions); //case B: returns unexpected value false
}));
echo($result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$myoptions` is outside of your function... try add `function ($var) use ($myoptions)` like

```
$result = filter_var($testVar, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => function ($var) use ($myoptions) {
    return validate_select($var, $myoptions);
}));
```

Comment: thnx. However, that still does not seem to work (returns false in described example) (How does your line of code 'know' to call function  validate_select()?